# Fragment Tabs on Android 2.2

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

Anyone have a working example of fragment tabs that works on Android 2.2 and support up to ICS? Every example out there don't seem to be working even after adding the compatibility packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example using an Activity with a TabHost and Fragments inside the tabs. It uses the compatibility library and works with current and older versions of Android.

If you installed the support library and the samples with your Android SDK you will have it on your disk already:

/extras/android/compatibility/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.java

Comment: I don't see those files for some reason i already installed the Support Libraries. EDIT: nvm found it

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Look  [FragmentsTabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java) and [FragmentTabsPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java) examples of ActionBarSherlock library.
Tested by me on Android 2.3 and 4.1. It works nicely and is completely reusable.